# Python Loop through Root Dir

Tags: python, loops, foreach, path, operating-system

I've been trying to figure out how I can loop through a root directory with sub directories and search for a file. If a specific file exists then run a script.

File structure example:
Root
--Folder 1
----TEST.txt
--Folder 2
----[no files]
--Folder 3
----TEST.txt

What I am trying to achieve is having the .py file in Root. When run it will loop over each folder in Root, if the file TEST.txt then do some processing.

Notes:
There will always be folders in Root
Where processing is needed there will be a file called TEST.txt
There will definitely be some folders that do *not* have TEST.txt

Pseudo code:
From Root open Folder 1. If TEST.txt is there then do some cool stuff and then 'cd ../' and repeat process but look in Folder 2.
Stop looping when all Folders have been checked.

Comment: Check out `os.walk` and `os.listdir` : https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Comment: Thanks for that, I never knew about those. Will do more research on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should be able to search all folders and sub folders for a file.

```
import os

thisdir = os.getcwd()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(thisdir):
    if 'TEST.txt' in files:
        #do some processing
```

Joining 'root' and the file name should be able to give you access to that file if you want to execute or analyze it somehow.

Comment: Perfect, (quickly tested in a VM) exactly what I needed. Thanks so much